# What is the correct name of this typographic pattern?

Tags: typography

What is the correct technical term for the swirls above and below the names in the image below?

[image]

Comment: "is the name of the name of the correct name" so what kind of the name game it is??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are flourishes. They could be considered calligraphic flourishes, as they are designed to resemble those drawn with a pen.

Comment: took me 10 years to finally learn that word! I was going with swirls and decorative elements myself until just now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is what i understood..

There is no name for such typographic patterns(till someone suggest :P), some elements are used to make it stand nothing else and those elements are called decoration...

They are Decorative swirls/Floral/Swooshes and used for decoration..

- [Swirls decorative brush set](http://www.myinkblog.com/my-10-favorite-swirls-decorative-brush-sets/)
- [Decorative elements](http://mediamilitia.com/decorative-elements-pack-33-free-vectors-brushes-and-images/)

Comment: Down voters can i ask the reason behind,answer already says till someone suggest...and we got the right answer..